# Reactjs + Express Twitter API "Could not authenticate you."

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create a very simple app that allows me to post a tweet. I am currently using React running on port 3000 and express server.js running on port 5000

my server.js has the following:

```
app.post("/twitter/message", async(req, res) => {

  const tweet = req.body.tweet;

  try {
      const response = await postToTwitter(tweet);
      res.json({
          message: 'Tweet successfully posted to twitter'
      });
      
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({
          message: 'Not able to post'
      });
  }

});

function postToTwitter(tweet) {
client.post(
  "statuses/update",
  { status: tweet },
  function (error, tweet, response) {
    if (error) log(error);
    /* log(tweet); // Tweet body. */
  }
);
}
```

I am then using a script on the index.html page to post the input tweet:

```
  <script>

      $('button').on('click', (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          const tweet = $('#tweet').val();

          // Post Tweet
          $.ajax({
              url: '/twitter/message',
              method: 'POST',
              data: {
                  tweet
              }
          })
              .then(() => {
                  alert('Data successfully posted');
                  console.log('Data successfully posted');
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                  alert('Error: ', error);
                  console.log('Error: ', error);
              });
      })
      

  </script>
```

This however is giving me the bellow error when I hit the post button:

```
[ { code: 32, message: 'Could not authenticate you.' } ]
```

If I use this exact same setup with just express it works perfectly fine, the issue occurs when trying to use react. Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly a CORS issue (which would show up in the frontend but not in Node/Backend).

If you're using some sort of API key to make the API request you're not showing it in this sample (don't show people your API key). By similar logic, do not have your API key on the client side, as anyone downloading your website would then have your Twitter API key. Instead, for multiple reasons it is better to have the backend be the one to make the API requests with your API key.

On the other hand if users are supposed to authenticate via O-Auth and you're supposed to pass a cookie with your authentication make sure you useCredentials on the request. `axios.post(BASE_URL + '/api', { withCredentials: true });` . Looks like you're using jquery so add the same withCredentials:

Try adding this to your options:

```
crossDomain: true,
xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
```

If you don't see a cookie when you type `document.cookie` in the browser that's probably a sign you're not authenticated in your computer.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to mention I'm actually using the npm Twitter package. The only code left out was my access tokens and consumer keys. Do you know how I would add these options to the Twitter package?

Comment: I think that on the client side you should not be putting your personal twitter Access tokens/consumer keys (anything client side is ultimately exposed to anyone accessing your site). Instead you have to either let the user oauth with twitter and use their own twitter account or keep your access tokens safely on the server side and proxy requests to twitter through your own server.